# Human brain or brains

Tags: word-usage

Should I use the singular or the plural form of *brain*? Would a native speaker say "human's brain" in my sentence?

"She studies parasites and how some of them affect human brain."

Comment: You would need an article before "brain" if you wanted to keep it singular. It would be correct to say, "She studies parasites and how some of them affect *the* human brain." If you didn't want to use the article, it would be the plural form, "brains." And, no, it would be incorrect to use possessive of "human."

Comment: @BreWoodsy but with possesive the brain should be singular. Right?

Comment: In this sentence, it would not be common to use the possessive form of "brain" at all. You would not typically say the "human's brain." It is sufficient to leave it at the "human brain." Having said that, "human's brain" isn't inherently wrong either.

Comment: @BreWoodsy, yes I meant in my sentence I can use "the human brain" or human brains but not human's brain. Right?

Comment: We can use 'brains' (plural) to mean the contents of an person's skull in set phrases such as 'he blew his brains out' or 'that boy's got brains'. Usually the organ in your skull is your brain (singular). Some parasites affect the human brain or (less usual) humans' brains.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It's either *a human's brain* (one indefinite human brain) or *the human brain* (the organ in general)